# In Mysql group_concat it returns some values up to limit only

Tags: php, mysql

In Mysql `group_concat`  it returns some values up to limit only i want all fields in the column which satisfied condition 
 up to 92 its working perfectly after that also same result
query is

```
SELECT group_concat(sn_mnums) as total  FROM `sms_notice` WHERE date(sn_dt)=curdate() and sn_status=0
```

here `sn_mnums` is coma separated field example 978688,878668,3434 like 
**count(total)** 
*is there any solution*

Comment: check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occur due to  `group_concat_max_len` size in your mysql.ini file

You will increase it by using query:-

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;// according to your requirment
```

Comment: just run this query `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000` before your query

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a default max length for `GROUP_CONCAT` (1024) characters. To change the default you can use `group_concat_max_len`

```
SET [SESSION|GLOBAL] group_concat_max_len = [NUMBER];
```